# Datepicker in Visual Studio 2010 vs WPF Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm wondering which datepicker is more powerful. I see there's already a Datepicker in Visual Studio, is the one in the wpf toolkit any better?

I'm looking for features such as just being able to display Year, Month, Day. I see datepicker in toolkit has DisplayMode which is good. But doesn't the regular one support this?

Comment: I think you're asking too much of a general question. It would be helpful to know which features you're looking for in either control.

Comment: I'm looking for a general answer. I'm wondering why there's two datepickers if there's already one included in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the WPF toolkit was created to fill the need for certain controls which did not exist at the time VS2008 shipped. .NET 3.5sp1 and earlier do not contain these controls natively, but .NET 4.0 does. Since VS2010 ships with .NET 4.0 you don't need to worry about the WPF toolkit at all unless you are developing for a target platform of .NET 3.5sp1 or earlier.

TL;DR: The WPF and .NET4 time picker control are effectively identical.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is this:

Visual Studio 2008 did not have a date-picker and a bunch of other controls as part of the default tool set that Visual Studio shipped with. To compensate for this, the WPF Toolkit was created. It continues to contain these controls today because there are still people out there who use Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF toolkit was basically consumed/authored by Microsoft and turned into controls for WPF/.NET 4.0, which is what comes with Visual Studio 2010. At least, that's my understanding. If you don't need to support .NET 3.5 SP1 clients I don't think there's any reason to continue using the WPF toolkit controls that are included out of the box.

A quick Google search also suggests from issues like this one: http://sharpfellows.com/post/WPF-Toolkit-ported-to-Net-40-and-VS-2010.aspx, that in fact if you only need the WPF 4 controls you'll have an easier time just skipping the toolkit entirely to avoid naming conflicts.